# AutoLayout: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints log unclear

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm getting the usual `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. ...` warning in the console.

One of the constraints in the list is:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe7bda00ff0 MyView:0x7fe7bbc934f0.height ==>"
```

Now, the meaning of the warning itself is pretty clear: some of the constraints are clashing and the engine is unable to satisfy all of them. This is pretty common when setting constraints via code, as I'm doing in this instance.

What's not clear to me is the meaning of that specific constraint. What does the missing right part of the equality means?

My guess is that is means that the `height` depends on the constraints set by its subviews. Is this correct?

Comment: It means that you have too many constraints, and they have conflicts. Did you set constraints in code? If so, please show us the code.

Comment: @SikhapolSaijit Yes they are set in code, and yes I know it the message means that there's a conflict. I'm not sure what that specific constraint without any right value means. I've updated the question to be more clear. Thanks.

Comment: If you set it in code, try setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` for all views involved with those added constraints.

Comment: Some guesses: you redundantly constrained a view's height to its height; you constrained a view's height to 0; you constrained a view's height to a `nil` view's attribute. You should break on the exception and see if you can't identify the view by its address. The Allocations instrument can help you find where an object was allocated.

Comment: I've never seen that before. It's almost like you've created a constraint with no second item and no second attribute. If you breakpoint and log out the details of that address, what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

In your constraints there is an extra constraints that not require.

For example,

Suppose you given a constraints to leading and trailing and also you are giving a width constraints that this will lead to the warning to the compiler. because  either you need a  constraints for width or trailing constraints otherwise compiler will confuse what to take width or trailing.

For auto layout you need to remember one thing for any view you need to make constrains like this that compiler knows about view x , y , width and height.